# zero locus of irreducible polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, riemann-surfaces

I am learning Riemann surfaces and one of the books I use is Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces by Rick Miranda. He mentions if $f(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}[z,w]$ is irreducible the zero locus is connected. He doesn't prove it. Do you guys have tips how to do this or some literature?

Kind regards

Comment: Which topology are you using - Zariski or Euclidean?

Comment: Right now still the euclidian one, the Zaraski topology get's introduced later.